# Refining an AutoHotkey script

Tags: script, autohotkey

The purpose of this script is:

1. The first two rows of hotkeys always effective.
2. The remaining hotkeys work at `NO TEXT INPUT` Status only. In other words, when the small vertical lines are flashing anywhere on the screen and  waiting for input text / digital, press <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>, the effect is equal to the normal original letters.

How can I do that?

```
Rwin::^space 
AppsKey::^w 

CapsLock::MButton 

z::PgUp 

x::PgDn 

*a up::send {shift up}{ctrl up}{LButton up}

*a:: 
GetKeyState, LButtonState, LButton ; 
if LButtonState = U ; 
send {shift down}{ctrl down}{LButton down} ; 
return 

*s up::send {shift up}{ctrl up}{RButton up} 

*s:: 
GetKeyState, RButtonState, RButton ; 
if RButtonState = U ; 
send {shift down}{ctrl down}{RButton down} ; 
return 

*q up::send {shift up}{ctrl up}{MButton up} 

*q:: 
GetKeyState, MButtonState, MButton ; 
if MButtonState = U ; 
send {shift down}{ctrl down}{MButton down} ; 
return
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect what type of cursor is currently displaying by looking at [A_Cursor](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm)

A_Cursor will be one of the following:

```
The type of mouse cursor currently being displayed. 
It will be one of the following words:
    AppStarting, Arrow, Cross, Help, IBeam, Icon, No, Size, SizeAll, SizeNESW, SizeNS, 
    SizeNWSE,     SizeWE, UpArrow, Wait, Unknown.
```

This code checks if there is a blinking cursor or not

```
if A_Cursor != Ibeam
    msgbox, Not Waiting for input
else
    msgbox, Waiting for input
return
```